# How to use Axios to consume an API and its endpoints and ensure that the first request and its endpoint become a single object?

Tags: typescript, axios

I am making a request using Axios and the PUT method to extract data; so far, it has been working as expected, and the JSON file is returned to me as shown in the attached image. However, I have a question about how I would make these requests also consume the endpoint corresponding to each object in the JSON. There is a parameter called idContrato that is the same as the one used to access the endpoint in the URL below. How can I make each object have getContratos and getItensContrato?

`https://prefeitura.uberaba.mg.gov.br/GRP/portalcidadao/webservices/contratos/getItensContrato?id=${idContrato}`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex3Am.png)

What I tried worked as expected; the website uses the PUT method in its requests and extracts the data as intended. Now, I don't know how to proceed due to a lack of knowledge. So, how would it be done, or what would I do to ensure that the object for each idContrato also includes the data from getItensContrato?

Comment: Is this contrato data stored somewhere? Let's say, in a SQL database?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Array filter function to return only `idContrato` from the original JSON object, then feed it to a new `Set` just to avoid duplicates. Then iterate through the Ids and make new calls for each and every one of them.

Ideally, you would be storing this data somewhere so you wouldn't have to fetch all of them every time, but in case you absolutely have to, you should fetch them recursively and take the next steps once all recursive calls had finished.

```
const contratoSet = new Set(response.data.filter(contrato => contrato.idContrato));

for (let idContrato of contratoSet) {
    axios.put(getContratosUrl + `?id=${idContrato}`)
    .then(response => {
        //(...)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        //(...)
    });
}
```